# Error in NbClus(x, distance = "euclidean", min.nc = 2, max.nc = 8, method = "complete", could not find function "NbClus"

Tags: r

Trying to run nbclus but I keep getting the following error after I install the package:

```
install.packages("NbClust")
set.seed(1)
x<-rbind(matrix(rnorm(100,sd=0.1),ncol=2),
         matrix(rnorm(100,mean=1,sd=0.2),ncol=2),
         matrix(rnorm(100,mean=5,sd=0.1),ncol=2),
         matrix(rnorm(100,mean=7,sd=0.2),ncol=2))
x
res<-NbClust(x, distance = "euclidean", min.nc=2, max.nc=8, 
         method = "complete", index = "ch")

Error in NbClus(x, distance = "euclidean", min.nc = 2, max.nc = 8, method 
= "complete",  : 
  could not find function "NbClus"
```

Anyone suggest what I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

first you need to load NbClust library

```
# install package
install.packages("NbClust")

# load library
library(NbClust)

# set seed 
set.seed(1)

# create a matrix
x<-rbind(matrix(rnorm(100,sd=0.1),ncol=2),
         matrix(rnorm(100,mean=1,sd=0.2),ncol=2),
         matrix(rnorm(100,mean=5,sd=0.1),ncol=2),
         matrix(rnorm(100,mean=7,sd=0.2),ncol=2))

# view matrix
x

# do NbClust stuff
res<-NbClust(x, distance = "euclidean", min.nc=2, max.nc=8, 
             method = "complete", index = "ch")
```